# How are Fourier coefficients calculated using the trapezoidal rule?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The analytic definition of the Fourier coefficient $a_k$ is given by:

$$a_k = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} f(t) \cos(kt) \ dt \tag 1$$

I'm struggling to understand how the Fourier coefficients are calculated using trapezoidal integration method. Applying the method to $(1)$ gives

$$ a_k = \frac{2 \pi}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \left(\frac{f(0) + f(2 \pi)}{2} \right) + \sum \limits_{j = 1}^{n-1} \cos \left(k \cdot \frac{2\pi j}{n} \right) \cdot f \left(\frac{2\pi j}{n} \right)$$

where

\begin{align}
x_j &= \frac{2\pi j}{n} \\\\
y_j &=
\begin{cases}
 f(x_j)&\text{if}\, 1 \leq j \leq n-1 \\\\
 \dfrac{f(0)+f(2\pi)}{2} & \text{if } j=0 \\
\end{cases}
\end{align}

because of $$ k x_j = w \cdot \frac{2\pi j}{n} = j \cdot x_k$$

$$a_w = \frac{2}{n} \cdot \left(y_0 + \sum \limits_{j = 1}^{n-1} \cos(jx_k) \cdot y_j \right) $$

The last two lines give me headaches. What is the purpose of the second last line. And how can I calculate $a_w$ when there is no w in the last line? Unfortunately I'm not even sure if it is correct since I have a hard time deciphering the handwritten lecture notes by my professor.

---

EDIT:
In the second last line. Since $ x_j = \frac{2\pi j}{n}$ it follows that $ k = w$. Then $x_k = x_j$ and $w=j$?

---

EDIT 2: Assuming that the considerations of my first edit are true, it would allow us to write the last sum as only dependent on $j$ since $x_j = x_k = \frac{2\pi j}{n}$ This would allow us to calculate $x_w = x_k$ by using the last sum.

A picture of the result so far. Blue line is original function. Orange line is approximation

[image: Result preliminary]

Comment: I have no idea..That is all information available...w seems to be the index of the Fourrier coefficient $a_w$

Comment: the sum in $\cos f$ should be an average ..

Comment: @GCab But isn't 2/n the factor for averaging?

Comment: I guess your $w$ should be a $k$. Your claim that $x_k = x_j$ is false since then $k=j$ for any index $k,j$ between $0$ and $n-1$. Just rewrite $k$ instead of $w$ and all becomes quite clear. I guess it is just a mistake in the notes you took.

Comment: @Jfischer I guess your right. From $k * x_j = j * x_k$ I concluded that $x_k = k*x_j/j$..Inserting this in the last sum gives $k*x_j$ which seemed the best way. It is still not working but I guess there is some other problem in the implementation or some other detail not explicitly covered in the script. (the script is hand-written by the prof not by me)

Comment: You keep introducing new symbolry in this question, but treating it as if it had been used before. For instance, after giving the trapezoidal version of the formula for $a_k$, you say "where" then *introduce* "$x_j, y_j$", which were not used before this. What is the "where" referring to? You introduce $w$ in a context that only makes sense if $w = k$ and make no use of $w$ in any sense where $k$ would not work as well. Why do you introduce this new variable, if it is just going to be the same as an existing one? Did $k$ need an alias for some reason?

Comment: And then you have the equation $k x_j = jx_k$, which is a simple consequence of the definition of $x_j$. But then you just drop the coefficients and decide $x_j = x_k$? That is not what the original equation says. $k$ and $j$ are different variables. $k$ is the index of the particular $a_k$ Fourier coefficient you are calculating. $j$ is a dummy variable of the summation used in calculating $a_k$ (now treated as a normal variable, as we are in a sense working within the confines of that sum). It takes on all values between $1$ and $n-1$, not just $k$.

Comment: Since no one has answered your question yet, there is no need to append edits; simply refine the question and incorporate what you learned from the comments.

Comment: I'll note that although the original motivation for this question seems to come from Fourier analysis, this question is really about understanding the trapezoidal rule in numerical integration. I suggest reading through any text and perhaps doing a few exercises focused entirely on the trapezoidal rule.

Comment: @PaulSinclair I omitted one line where second formula is written with $\frac{2 \pi j}{n} = x_j. f(\frac{2 \pi j}{n}) = y_j$ Should have included it as well. See the comment by JFischer. I guess the best explanation is that there is no w but only terrible handwriting. You're correct that there is no need for w.

Comment: @davidlowryduda The exercise is about calculating the Fourrier coefficients using the trapecoidal rule.

Comment: And yes my considerations regarding $x_j = x_k$ are obviously bogus I really couldn't think clearly anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding the last line a bit, assuming that what appeared to you as "$w$" is just a poorly-written $k$ (you did say it was hand-written and you were having trouble deciphering the handwriting), we have

$$
k x_j = k \cdot \frac{2\pi j}{n} = jk \cdot \frac{2\pi}{n}
 = j \cdot \frac{2\pi k}{n} = j \cdot x_k.
$$

Nowhere is it trying to imply that $k = j$ or $x_k = x_j.$
It's just using the facts that multiplication is associative and commutative
(with division defined as multiplication by the multiplicative inverse).

The purpose of the step is a little unclear. I suppose it saves a few multiplications when you do each sum as an independent calculation with no precomputation (as opposed to calculating all possible $x_j$ terms first and recording them somewhere where you can easily retrieve them during the integration).

Comment: I don't get it either..He could just as well have written $k \cdot x_j$ in the last sum then it would have been clear what has to be calculated...

Comment: I suspect it was indeed to speed up the actual calculation of $a_k$. You calculate $\alpha :=\frac{2\pi}n$ first. With $k\cdot x_j$, for each term, you need to calculate $x_j = \alpha\cdot j \cdot k$, two multiplications per term. With $j\cdot x_k$, you can calculate $x_k = \alpha\cdot k$ at the first, and just do a single multiplication $j\cdot x_k$ for each term. At one time, such techniques could increase speed. But unless you are either working by hand, or are doing a truly massive calculation, you would not notice the difference between the two now.